# How to remove redundancy from my C++ test code

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a cpp test file

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTests
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTests)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            someCommonMethod();

            Assert::AreEqual(add(1, 2) , 3);
        }

        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod2)
        {
            someCommonMethod();
            Assert::AreEqual(add(1, 3), 4);
        }
    };
}
```

How can I remove the redundancy or extract the code to a class so that someCommonMethod() is called for every TEST_METHOD I create.
I went through the documentation regarding [TEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/test/using-microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: Make it a private function of your UnitTest class?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#Initialize_and_cleanup

Comment: @Moia : I can use that but the catch is I have different Test classes and the someCommonMethod() is required in the different Test classes Test _Method

Comment: So a collection of external helper function or classes...

Comment: test code is no different to normal one, you can create an header (and implementation file if appropriate) and includes it to each of your test files.

Comment: In general, I recommend against having common code blocks for unit tests.  It makes the unit tests harder to modify and evolve; more rigid; less flexible.  Code should follow DRY (*don't repeat yourself*), but unit tests should follow WET (*write expressive tests*).  Along with all the other unit test considerations:  no global state, can be run in parallel, no interdependencies, no loops/branches, arrange/act/assert, no external dependencies, 100% reliable, test one-and-only-one thing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with what @Alan Birtles wrote. You do have https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#Initialize_and_cleanup.

I would caution against complex common code though.

Given following scenario:

```
TEST_CLASS(UnitTests)
{
public:
    
    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1LogicalGroupBasedOnFeature1) {}
    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod2LogicalGroupBasedOnFeature1) {}

    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1LogicalGroupBasedOnFeature2) {}
    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod2LogicalGroupBasedOnFeature2) {}

}
...
```

If you find yourself making initialization complex (I would consider even 1 "if" statement complex in init), either create a new class or do copy paste.

You should never need to unit test the unit test code itself.